# Не включается проект в Unity hub

Tags: unity3d

[image: После создания проекта он не включился а пявилась вот такая ошибка]

После создания проекта он не включился а пявилась вот такая ошибка

Comment: `Не удалось запустить процесс Unity Package Manager. Убедитесь, что процесс [D:/проги/...UnityPackageManager.exe] не заблокирован Windows Defender или какой-либо другой антивирусной программой. Нажмитие Retry, чтобы перезапустить Unity и переоткрыть проект, нажмите Diagnose, чтобы запустить диагностику инструментов Unity Package Manager`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса